# Is there a way to pass parameters to TestNG test without using @DataProvider & parameters in XML?

Tags: java, testng

Currently, I'm using `@DataProvider` which reads data from excel and passes it to only one **`@Test`**. Generally, this data contains execution flow of a test case, which enables me to run different test cases parallel eliminating the dependency on modifying the `testng.xml`.

The problem with above approach is I'm not able to prioritize or maintain dependency externally. Is there a way, wherein I can launch `@Test` contained in TestNG class from another class along with **parameters** so that I can maintain dependency mentioned in the excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

`@Factory` annotated methods are there to help.
You can call constructors of other test classes inside and then access parameters in `@Test`, `@Before*` and `@After*` annotated methods.

```
public class MainProvider {

    @Factory(dataProvider = "main", dataProviderClass = MainProvider.class)
    public Object[] prepare(ParameterType first, ParameterType second) {
        return new Object[]{new SimpleTest(firstParameter, secondParameter)};
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "main")
    public Iterator<Object[]> dataProvider() {
        List<Object[]> parameters = new ArrayList<>();

        //Fill it with your data (this can be, of course, in a loop):
        parameters.add(new Object[] {parameter1, anotherParameter1});
        parameters.add(new Object[] {parameter2, anotherParameter2});

        return parameters.iterator();
    }
}
```